# Real time agenda with javascript and json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a div on a website that needs to be a real time agenda for a list of events. I have the events loaded through a json file and am using javascript to populate the div with the data from the file.

The problem is that the data displays stacked item by item in one column within a div, I need to now split the div into three separate columns/divs. One for events happening now, next, and coming soon. Ex) one event is at 7am, next is 7:30, and coming soon is 8am.

But I am not able to select each item and move it using css since the code just populates by one item upon page load and I cannot see an index for each item (video side content item) over and over to display what events are necessary.

This would be a lot easier if I could just format the items being populated into three separate columns through css, but I can't figure out how to do this.

By the way this site is written using FlexBox, hence why there is a "row" in one of the divs.

Also can someone please point in the right direction as to how to get this to be real time? Or any other helpful solution that could achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[picture of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojo6P.jpg)

**Function to populate the data**

```
function agendaRealTimeUpdate() {
    if ($('.real-time-agenda').length !== 0) {
        videoSideContentType = 'agenda';
        $.getJSON("ac.json", function(data) {
            var sessions = data.session;
            var contentString = '';
            var currentSessionIndex;
            var currentSession;
            var currentTime;
            var currentDay;
            var title;
            var time;
            var room;
            var description;
            var d;
            var i = 0;

            d = new Date();

            //gets the current time and returns it in a string with 3-4 digits EX: "1000" = 10 am 
            currentTime = parseInt(d.getHours().toString() + ((d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes()).toString());

            currentDay = d.getDate();

            // this loop runs as long as we haven't figured out which session matches the time
            while (currentSessionIndex === undefined && i < sessions.length) {

                //this takes the current time and compares it to the sessions start and end times
                if ((currentTime >= sessions[i].startTime && currentTime <= sessions[i].endTime) && 
                    currentDay === sessions[i].day && 
                    sessions[i].track === "none") 
                {
                        currentSessionIndex = i;
                }

                i++;
            }

            if (currentSessionIndex === undefined) {
                currentSessionIndex = 0;
            }

            // This function finds the sessions that come after the identified current session
            function findNextSessions() {
                var sessionsCopy = sessions.slice(); //make a copy of the sessions array so we aren't altering it when we remove indexes

                for (var z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
                    var index = currentSessionIndex + z; 

                    // breaks out of the loop if the next session is undefined
                    if (sessionsCopy[index] === undefined) {
                        z = 2;
                    }

                    currentSession = sessionsCopy[index];

                    // loops through the sessions and if the session has a track it is removed from the sessionsCopy array
                    while (currentSession.track !== "none") {
                        console.log('has a track: ' + currentSession.track);
                        sessionsCopy.splice(index, 1);
                        currentSession = sessionsCopy[index];
                    }

                    time = currentSession.timeString !== undefined ? "<div class='video-side-content__time'><b>Time:</b> " + currentSession.timeString + "</div>" : ''; 
                    room = currentSession.room !== undefined ? "<div class='video-side-content__room'><b>Room:</b> " + currentSession.room + "</div>" : '';
                    title = currentSession.title !== undefined ? "<div class='video-side-content__secondary-title'>" + currentSession.title + "</div>" : '';

                    description = currentSession.content !== undefined ? "<div class='video-side-content__content'>" + currentSession.content + "</div>" : '';
                    contentString += "<div class='video-side-content__item'>" + time + room + title + description + "</div>";

                }
            }
            findNextSessions();
            $('.real-time-agenda').html(contentString);
        });
    }
}
```

**Div I'm working with**

```
 <div class="row__item">
    <h2 class="video-side-content__title"><img src="img/agenda-icon.png">&nbsp;Thursday. Sept. 22</h2>
    <div class="row__flex-container">
      <div class="row__item video-side-content__strip video-side-content__strip-left"> </div>
      <div class="row__item video-side-content__row">
        <div class="video-side-content">
          <div class="video-side-content__items">
            <div class="video-side-content__item">
              <h2 class="count-down__sub-header"><br>
                SHOWING NOW</h2><br>
              <div class="real-time-agenda">
                <!--data populates upon page load from the json file
                    It lays the data out as: Time, Title, Room, Description-->

              </div>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So create 3 divs inside of your `real-time-agenda` div. One for each category. Sort your data based on now, next, and coming soon then insert them into the appropriate divs. Then it's just a matter of aligning those 3 divs correctly.

Comment: That's the thing. The div for real time agenda appears with the data already loaded regardless if there is a div in it or not.

Comment: It looks like your `agendaRealTimeUpdate` replaces the contents of `real-time-agenda`. I'm telling you to put 3 divs *inside* of `real-time-agenda` by modifying that function.

Comment: @Mike C I'm sorry I wasn't able to get back into these files until today. I am basically picking this up from a previous coworker and have no idea what to do. I do not understand what you mean by putting the div inside the function? The div is the function...

Comment: I didn't say to put the 3 divs in the function, I said to put [3 divs inside of `real-time-agenda`](http://pastebin.com/B2dTJg8g) and the way to do that is to modify the `agendaRealTimeUpdate` function.